# Question about solution: Poisson process & conditional expectation

Tags: self-study, conditional-expectation, poisson-process, exponential-distribution

> **Given the following problem:**
> Alice shows up at an Athena cluster at time $0$ and spends her time exclusively in typing emails. The times that her emails are sent are a Poisson process with rate $\lambda_A$ per hour. Let $Y_1$ time at which Alice’s first  email was sent. You show up at time $1$ and you are told that Alice has sent exactly one email so far. What is the conditional expectation of $Y_1$ given this information?
>
> **Solution:**
> Let $A$ be the event $\{$exactly one arrival in the interval $[0,1]\}$. Given $A$, the times in this interval are equally likely for the arrival $Y_1$. Thus,
> $E[Y_1 | A] = \frac{1}{2}$.

I am completely lost because $Y_1 \sim\exp(\lambda_A)$, so shouldn't I just calculate expected value for exp. rv on interval $[0,1]$? Why is my approach wrong?

Comment: Your approach wouldn't work because it doesn't account for the fact there was just *one* email sent during that interval. If you contemplate the continuation of the process, eventually there would have been a second email sent *after* time $1:$ you must also condition on this fact.

Comment: @whuber: As usual thank you for reply! The fact that I integrate over interval [0,1] and not [0, $\infty$] doesn't account for this? I mean I know that it happend in [0,1], I just need to get E for rv on this interval. I really can't understand how event A (information A) transform my rv from exp. into uniform...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a bayesian problem. Time $Y_1$ *if you don't know the number of mails at time 1*, is exponentially distributed, you got that right. But when you get the additional information that at time 1 Alice only sent one e-mail, you have to update your distribution of $Y_1$. Applying Bayes rule:

$$p(Y_1|emails_1 = 1) \propto p(emails_1 = 1|Y_1)p(Y_1).$$

So you have the exponential distribution $p(Y_1)$ that we already understand, and the other stranger thing $p(emails_1 = 1|Y_1)$ which is the probability of not having any other mail sent after the first one, until time 1, given $Y_1$. It is equal to $\int_1^\infty p(Y_2|Y_1) dY_2$ and it raises as $Y_1$ gets closer to 1. Actually, as the integral of an exponential function is exponential as well, it turns out, with few passages, that $p(emails_1 = 1|Y_1) = exp(1-Y_1)$, so:

$$p(Y_1|emails_1 = 1) \propto exp(Y_1)exp(1-Y_1) \propto 1$$

where $exp$ is the esponential distribution density, whatever is the (equal) rate parameter. Last passage is easily verifiable from multiplying those exponential densities.

Your updated distribution of $Y_1$ is uniform, and expected value can be immediately derived.

---

If you'd like a much shorter, more intuitive explanation, mind that Poisson process is symmetrical, and that the distribution of $Y_1$ is the same looked from 0 and from 1, so of course its expected value must be 0.5. This explanation doesn't account for the rest of its distribution though.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I more or less understand as explanation. Didn't you mistake in integral  range, from $1-Y_1$ to $\infty$? $p(emails_1 = 1|Y_1)=P(Y_2 \ge 1-y_1)$, where $Y_2$ is also exp?

Comment: no I don't think so. $Y_2$ is the time of the second email being sent, and has an exponential distribution that starts at $Y_1$. That integral goes from 1 onwards because we need $Y_2$ to be greater than 1.

Comment: but given time $y_1$ between $[0,1]$ what we need is that $Y_2 \ge 1-y_1$ to be sure that second event doesn't happen in $[0,1]$.

Comment: There's nothing "Bayesian" about this question: it's purely a matter of computing a conditional probability.

Comment: @Sharov I call $Y_2$ what you call $Y_1+Y_2$

Comment: @carlo: Still can't understand you: $Y_2$ is exponential inteval which start from $y_1$ till some time in future > 1. $Y_2$ as exact time (not interval) is not exp. distributed. We just need to calc. probability that this second interval is $\ge 1 -y_1$. Seems to me we speak about the same in different terms.

Comment: @whuber: Can you provide your solution based not on a Bayesian approach?

Comment: @Sharov The solution quoted in the question is not Bayesian.

Comment: @whuber: But solution from carlo is, and his solution seems more clear to me.

Comment: the quoted solution doesn't explain how to reach it. ok that this problem is not bayesian in the classical/epystemological sense of the term, but it is in the sense that the required conditional probability is in the bayesian form p(model | data)

Comment: @Sharov yes we were saying the same thing in different terms.